# What did I break and what do I need to replace?

Tags: wheels, gmc, steering-wheel, suburban, break

My car slid and went over a center divider. I am very new to auto repair, but am wanting to learn and do it myself. Sadly, I am not very familiar with the parts so I can't really say what broke other than it is the left front tire. Please let me know what looks broken and what needs replacing.

[image: 1999 GMC Suburban 2500]
**1999 GMC Suburban 2500**

Answer (score 6):

You broke the knuckle. It's hard to say what else is damaged, but the knuckle, wheel bearing(s), hub (may be a single assembly) and lower ball joint need to be replaced. It may need the lower control arm, possibly the upper ball joint as well. You'd need an alignment after all is said and done.

It also looks like you could use some sway bar links.

Comment: I'd say definitely needs a new lower control arm. The ball joint is ripped out!

Answer (score 5):

See Ben's answer for parts you likely damaged. In order to conduct this repair, the tools you will need are:

- large size (bigger than 15 mm, 1/2 inch drive) deep sockets
- 1/2 inch drive breaker bar (24 inch long)
- 1/2 inch drive torque wrench (one that goes to 100 ft-lbs)
- large size wrenches (bigger than 15 mm)
- floor jack (either trolley or bottle type, make sure it can: 1) lift the weight of your truck, 2) it can physically fit under your truck and 3) it can lift high enough to get your wheels off the ground)
- jack stands (2 would be ideal so the entire front of the truck can be supported)
- penetrating oil (suspension and steering repairs often involve rusted bolts)

Comment: Once you have finished the repair then only finally tighten the suspension bolts once the vehicle is back on the ground. This is because you can pre-load the rubber bushes if the bolts are fully tightened when the suspension is relaxed. This can lead to early failure.